# How do I send my stripe webhook to my Heroku app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, stripe-payments

I've integrated Stripe into my javascript app which works fine in my test environment using ngrok but once I switch to prod, my app is timing out as users attempt to *leave* the Stripe checkout screen.

The Stripe webhook kicks error `Timed out connecting to remote host` and I think it's because I have the wrong endpoint.

**Testing endpoint**

```
https://6752-136-62-45-90.ngrok.io/users/stripe/webhook
```

**Live endpoint**

```
https://myapp.com/users/stripe/webhook
```

Everything else in the integration appears to work -- the customer is still created and the billing goes through but I need the endpoint code to run because it builds some critical infrastructure in the `user` profile.

I also have SSL encryption setup and DNS target on my Heroku application so I'm wondering if I should be using the DNS target or the Heroku app name for the endpoint instead of my domain.

**My question**

I can't really find any documentation on this but how do I configure my Stripe endpoint with my Heroku-hosted app?

Answer (score 1):

You can test by setting the Heroku app name directly to check if it works to narrow down the issue. If it still doesn't, then most likely it's due to network issue.

`Timed out connecting to remote host` usually means that the server is not responding. This is likely due to network configuration such as firewall blocking the Stripe IP addresses. I'd recommend checking your network configuration and ensure that Stripe domains/IP addresses are in the allowed list: https://stripe.com/docs/ips